# Key used in shortcut. How to unmap?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I'm having some trouble pressing the <kbd>`</kbd> key (I had to copy/paste it here) on my Ubuntu.

It acts like a weird <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> now.

When checking with `xkbevd`, I get

```
^[
```

How can I reset this and get the key back?

Is there a way to see what's grabbing the event?

This is what it looks like in keyboard layout:

[image]

How can I unmap 'escape' from this key?

`xev` shows:

pressing <kbd>backtick</kbd> (no ctrl, no shift, just the key):

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 41199509, (277,668), root:(314,767),
    state 0x0, keycode 49 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 9
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 41199559, (277,668), root:(314,767),
    state 0x0, keycode 49 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 9
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 41201255, (277,668), root:(314,767),
    state 0x0, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 41201320, (277,668), root:(314,767),
    state 0x0, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Does running `xmodmap -e 'keycode 49=grave'` solve it? I think Ubuntu might not be using `xmodmap` anymore. If so, have a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/347382/85695).

Comment: @terdon, YEEEEES!! thank you! it works now! please post it as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Cool, which one? The `xmodmap`? And does it survive a reboot?

Comment: yeah, the `xmodmap`. It isn't persisted after reboot, but i can fix that in  `bashrc`

Comment: No, don't fix it in the `.bashrc`, read the answer I linked to above, that should let you fix it across reboots.

Comment: Please see updated answer. The first version disabled the tilde. It turns out that you also need to specify what it does when shift is pressed. Sorry!

Comment: @terdon, Thanks for the update. I ran into that issue right after you posted the solution. Checking the answer you provided in the first comment, I managed to update the `xmodmap` command to your final answer. You just beat me to it ;) I was about to comment the update. Anyway, you're a lifesaver!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the action associated with a key using `xmodmap`. In your case, you want:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 49=grave asciitilde'
```

That sets the key with the keycode 49 to print a grave accent, a backtick, and a tilde when combined with shift. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184908/22222) for a few more details.